# Creating an Object with a Class as Datatype in Java

Tags: java, object, types

```
Class Person{ 
     String name;
     int phone;
     Date meeting;

     public Person(String name, int phone, Date meeting){
          this.name = name;
          this.phone = phone;
          this.meeting = meeting;
}
```

The Person class uses the Date class as a datatype

```
Class Date{
int day;
int month;
int year;

public Date(int day, int month, int year){
     this.day = day;
     this.month = month;
     this.year = year;
}
```

I want to create an object (a Person) with the values name, phone and meetingdate for example like this:

```
Class TestPerson{

#Example 1#

Date Johnsmeeting = new Date(1,1,2021);
Person John = new Person("John",12345678, Johnsmeeting);

#Example 2#
Person John = new Person("John",12345678, new Date(1,1,2021));
```

Do I need to create an extra Object for the Date?
Is there a better way to code this?

Comment: why is it bad to create a date object?

Comment: The only bad thing is to have a class Date, use LocalDate instead

Comment: There is nothing wrong to create Objects like this, it is clearer than without new keyword, only thing as Joakim says: don't use old time api, use java.time.LocalDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct in instantiating a `Date` object to be passed to the constructor of `Person`.

Both your examples 1 and 2 are correct and valid. There one difference is that in example # 1 where you retain a reference to `Date` class, if that class were mutable, then further down any code that mutates that object would be mutating the very same `Date` object referenced by the `Person` object. The code in `Person` might be surprised to see the value of the date changing for no apparent reason. There are a few ways around this problem including: (a) Make your `Date` class entirely immutable, (b) Pass a copy/clone of the object, or (c) Use your example # 2 syntax to avoid inadvertently messing with an object in use elsewhere.

You code is instantiating another object as well. The literal `"John"` is a special syntax for instantiating a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) object.

I am not sure what about this process bothers you. Perhaps you could edit your Question to explain the friction point in your understanding.

---

Your code has other issues, by the way.

Do not invent your own `Date` class. Java offers its industry-leading date-time framework in the *java.time* classes. Use `LocalDate` objects for your purpose. The *java.time* classes use factory methods rather than `new` constructors.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , 1 , 23 ) ;
```

…or use an enum object for the month.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

Follow Java conventions to make your code easier to read. Class names start with initial cap, variable names do not. Both use camel-case. So `Johnsmeeting` should be `johnMeeting`.

An numeric type such as `int` is not generally used for phone numbers. Phone numbers are complicated in the real world, and may involve various parts, and may involve text. Furthermore, numbers are for representing quantities or position (ordinal or index). A phone number is neither.

Java 16 will bring the new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature. This is a new abbreviated way to define a class that is mainly about immutably carrying data. The compiler implicitly writes the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and the `toString`. Your `Person` might be appropriate to write as a record.

Here is your entire `Person` class as a record.

```java
public record Person( String name , String phone , LocalDate meeting ) 
{
}
```